# how to use wordpress to edit an existing website built with bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, web, content-management-system

I have a website built with bootstrap, now I want to use wordpress as the content management system for my own website, how do I link them together? Or do I have to rebuild my website with bootstrap? Any help are appreciated. Thank u very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See theme structure in WP https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
You can easily develop theme. There are many site assisting to create theme. 
You can create any site whatever framework using like bootstrap.